# Python: Efficient way to split JSON from pandas.to_json() into smaller chunks

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am working with multiple pandas dataframes of varying sizes and calling an API that is limited to 10MB per post.  Some of the data that I'm transmitting exceeds 50MB.  I have functional code that is building the JSON manually, but I'd like to find a more efficient way to do so using the pandas.to_json() function (ideally, but not necessarily).

I'm relatively new to Python and the best method I've found is this article: https://python.plainenglish.io/split-big-json-file-into-small-splits-4e4b1b90e304, but likely without writing to disk.

Can this be done more efficiently?

Edit: I also need to set the index for the pandas.to_json to start with a specific number if possible.

Comment: It is nontrivial to split a JSON. It is trivial to split a dataframe.

Comment: @Amadan, thank you for the direction, very helpful.  Any insight into how to limit the size of each split?

Comment: `[df[i:i+n] for i in range(0, df.shape[0], n)]`, where `n` is number of rows you want for each split.